# Placing a div exactly above a moving div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I am customizing [jquery-ui slider(range)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range). The two corner points(div) are draggable. I wish to place the exact value of the slider just above the corner points but i am unable to do So, can anyone suggest how the position of the div containing the current values can be changed using javascript ?

Comment: I used `position:relative` with css in similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it using CSS - make the value div a child of the slider div, then use `position: relative` on the value div with a negative `top`

```
<div id="Slider">
    <div id="Value" style="position: relative; top: -100px; width:...">
    </div>
</div>
```